# Alpha Beta Pruning

Tags: chess, typescript

I'm implementing alpha-beta pruning for a chess engine in TypeScript

Here's the code:

```
public static alphabetta(board: Board, player: Player = Player.CPU, move?: Move, depth: number = 0,
    α: number = -Infinity, β: number = +Infinity): EvaluatedMove {

    const { gameOver, winner } = board;
    if (gameOver) {
      if (winner === Player.CPU) return EvaluatedMove.from(move, MAX_SCORE - depth);
      if (winner === Player.Human) return EvaluatedMove.from(move, depth - MAX_SCORE);
    }

    if (depth >= MAX_DEPTH) {
      return EvaluatedMove.from(move, this.score(board, depth));
    }

    const opposingPlayer = opponent(player);
    const possibleMoves = board.possibleMoves(player);

    if (player === Player.CPU) {
      let result = <EvaluatedMove>{ score: α };
      for (const possibleMove of possibleMoves) {
        const newBoard = board.makeMove(possibleMove);
        result = max(result, this.alphabetta(newBoard, opposingPlayer, possibleMove, depth + 1, α, β));
        α = Math.max(α, result.score);
        if (β <= α) break;
      }
      return result;
    } else {
      let result = <EvaluatedMove>{ score: β };
      for (const possibleMove of possibleMoves) {
        const newBoard = board.makeMove(possibleMove);
        result = min(result, this.alphabetta(newBoard, opposingPlayer, possibleMove, depth + 1, α, β));
        β = Math.min(β, result.score);
        if (β <= α) break;
      }
      return result;
    }
```

for full context here's a [pull request](https://github.com/venil7/chess/pull/2) on Github,
I used this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) and this [paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2002sp/lectures/rec21.htm) for refernce, tho they have slightly different pseudocode.

In my case I want `alphabetta()` not only return heuristic weight of a move but also the move itself, hence the slightly different implementation and signature

However both examples suggest that the algorithm may return moves that are not immediate (but may rather happen further down in game), which confuses me.

Any suggestions as to how this can be improved?
My (non pruning minimax implementation from the same repo is doing just that)

Comment: Sorry to sound a bit harsh, but does this code work? "[B]oth examples suggest that [the] algorithm may return moves that are not immediate". Notice that `v` in the Cornell algorithm is *not* a move, it is a score. I suspect that trying to return `result` as you have done will give you a move much further down the tree. This is, roughly speaking, why the scoring is decoupled from actually making the moves.

Comment: You didn't return the move, but only the score. Why?

Comment: The algorithm looks very similar to Wikipedia. Although the implementation look very slow, but it looks functional to me.

Comment: @Dair no it doesn't work, and hence this question

Comment: Off you go to stackoverflow then. [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954)

Comment: The algorithm is indeed correct. However, your details are missing. Why would you return like that for game over? How do you check for game over?